# Cannot connect to remote MSSQL database from stacked docker container

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a problem with connecting to existing remote MSSQL database from inside of a docker container running in stack.

1. My application consists of three modules (backend, frontend and haproxy)
2. Backend module is written in Java (SpringBoot app) and it's also the one that needs to connect do remote MSSQL database (by remote I mean placed on different sever, separate of docker part).
3. I have the following docker compose file:

[image]

4. I start the stack by using following command:

   ```
   docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp
   ```
5. The result is, all containers are up and running, but spring app reports that connection to DB is timed out:

[image]

Server seems to be configured properly, I am able to access the host from container through telnet.

When running independently (even from docker container) backend app is able to connect to database with no problems, while stacked with docker-compose however it's unable to connect to the very same db.

I've also tried to provide db server IP instead of host name - no success.

Maybe setting up networks section in docker compose would do the trick?

Comment: The mssql instance is running outside of the docker stuff?

Comment: Yep. It's a separate server.

Comment: Is the IP to the server correct? How and where do you run it? Because it looks like an internal (network) IP instead of a global IP. When you stack a docker application it gets its own internal network causing ip addresses like 10.x.x.x to point to other containers, this can be the cause why your application can't find the remote mssql server.

Comment: Yes, IP is correct. It's working as a part of internal corporate infrastructure.
Is there a way to avoid these conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was caused by networks overlapping.

Adding network configured as show below, allowed either to connect to my remote database and keep my endpoints hidden:

```
networks:
    backend:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.40.0/26
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Another thing you can do is to use `host.docker.internal` instead of the IP address of the database. This **ONLY** works on docker for windows or docker for mac.

Source: [I want to connect from a container to a service on the host](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

**OLD, only works when not in swarm mode**

You need to specify that docker should use the same network as the host, you can do this in the following way:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      dockerfile: web-app/something
    ports:
       - 8080:8080
    network_mode: "host"
```

Reference: [Use host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Comment: Building stack which ses network_mode option just gives me the **Ignoring unsupported options: network_mode** info.
It seems that it's not supported under docker for desktop.

Do You maybe have any other ideas how to implement that in docker-compose?

Comment: I have updated my answer with another option, i hope this one works for you. If not, please let me know :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the solution. Even that I managed to run docker and host on the same network, my endpoints became public (what is highly unwanted behavior). I found another solution, which I posted under this question.